# Create and call actor from another actor in actix

Tags: rust, rust-actix

I am using `actix` to implement some simple processing logic in rust. The idea is that I have an actor type `Parent` which makes some decision and sometimes needs to create a `Child` actor, send message to it and get response. I noticed that `actix` `Handler` cannot be `async` therefore not allowing me to create an actor and receive response from it.

Is there a way to call an actor from another actor in `actix`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [into_actor](https://actix.rs/actix/actix/fut/future/trait.WrapFuture.html#tymethod.into_actor) to turn a Future into an ActorFuture.
You can find an example of sending a message and using the result [here](https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/1e1767135d87bba84747c397fa8aa4d9904460c9/websockets/chat/src/session.rs#L74)

Comment: Please add an example to your answer.
Links can change, and there is no guarantee they will work in the future.